# Folder organization

Tags: directory

So I am taking a web development class and in most of my classes they’ve been teaching us to keep our files separate. For instance, I have a public folder and an includes folder. In my includes folder I have my database information and functions. So here is where my issue is: I am trying to post a site in godaddy and when I try to set it up their tech support told me I should place all my files in the public folder. Is that really true? I thought I would need to place my includes(private) folder in another place; if so, where should I be storing it?

Answer (score 0):

GoDaddy may not be the best source of advice. When you SSH into your account (or use the File Manager) you should see your login dir which will IIRC have a www or html dir (and sometimes both, one symlinked to the other). Those are your public webroot/DOCROOT locations. Make a dirtree of your own as a *sibling* to the www/html dir and use that for your include tree.

When you need the absolute path to your directory tree in order to know where to grab your includes, you can get that from the GoDaddy admin interface - https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/58/finding-your-hosting-accounts-absolute-path